# New install of ModX Revo 2.2.10 - Get 'Unexpected token <:' on every manager page

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I've just installed Revo 2.2.10.

Whenever I open a new page in manager I get a pop up box saying

`Unexpected token <:`

Would anyone know what this means and what I can do to fix it?

(Ive installed ModX in a subdirecty, but am not using FURLs yet if that makes a difference)

The error I see in the logs is:

```
[Fri Dec 06 20:45:13 2013] [error] [client 101.XXX.XX.XX] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/mysite/public_html/newsite/connectors/security/user.php, referer: http://www.mysite.com.au/newsite/manager/
```

Comment: Nothing to say without apache error logs.

Comment: @Vasis Ive added the error I get in the logs above

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'd suggest:

1. Empty your core/cache folder
2. Click in manager menu Security->Flush permissions + Flush all sessions.
3. Logout and login again.
4. Clear your browser cache.
   Even for subfolder installations I have .htaccess (FURL is on):

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

Not the same modx version but it may help...

http://forums.modx.com/thread/77398/modx-2-2-4-unexpected-token

Answer (score 0):

Check your resource usage for your installation - specifically hitting virtual memory limits.

After many attempts to track down this problem on my Revo installation and getting nowhere I have come to the conclusion that this error is due to hitting virtual memory limits on my hosting package. Unfortunately I'd have to upgrade to a VPS package to increase my limits with my existing provider so I haven't been able to confirm this yet.